# Drop and execute file in target application

Tags: c#, wpf

I got struck with drag and drop in WPF. What I have is a local path to some file which is bind to Datagrid.

Now when user drag file and drop on desktop I am able to create shortcut for that file which is fine. But what extra I need is if user drop that file on some media player say window media player it should play that file.

```
                var url = @"filepath.mp4";
                //create shortcut in temp folder...and return that location
                var shortCutUrl = AddShortCut(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url), url);  
                string[] array = new string[] { shortCutUrl };
                var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, array, true);
                //now drop that file to whatever location
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

It seems media player is not reading *.lnk extension but VLC do. Please suggest if I am missing something or I am on wrong path.

Comment: Well, of course. `lnk` is not a transparent mapping to a file, it's something the target application must explicitly unravel. Most applications don't - why should they? `lnk`s are designed to launch executables, not to be passed to a media player. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Luaan, what i need is if user drop file on desktop or any other folder it should create shortcut to that file there, else if it drop mp4 file on media player then it should run that file.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something you should be doing. Those two are very different operations, so don't pretend both are `Copy` - allow `Copy` and `Link`. If the user wants to create a link, he can hold `Alt` while dragging. If he wants to play the file in another application, he's not going to hold `Alt`. You're imposing your own will on how the drag and drop contract is supposed to work, that's not very user friendly.

Comment: that why i am worried, one of my colleague working on mac application with same features, and mac is intelligent to decide what need to do in such case

Comment: You're lying to Windows. How do you propose Windows should figure out that you actually intended to provide a link to the original file, rather than copying the newly created `lnk` file? You're telling it to do exactly that! If you want to create a link, use `DragDropEffects.Link` with the original file. Stop doing "clever" hacks, and just use the feature the way it's designed to be used :)

Comment: agreed, i play a trick there but Link is somehow not working. of course i tried with Link, but i really don't understand what format should i give to DataObject, please suggest. and i also googled it for example with link but unable to find any

Comment: Well, it's a bit trickier. The stuff that .NET exposes for that isn't quite enough, you'll need to dig into the underlying API documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Or you can just have a look at how Explorer does it, by being a target for its own drop operation. Of course, Explorer cheats a bit, so it isn't exactly easy.